# Sequelize transaction prevent updating row

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

When I use the transaction in an update query, it prevents updating the row. Here is what I've done:

```js
let t = await sequelize.transaction();
let updated = User.update({
    lastName: 'new lastname',
    firstName: 'new firstname'
}, 
{
where: { email:'zzz@yyy.com' },
// doesn't update with transaction
// transaction: t
})
.then(success(res))
```

Btw, it updates `updatedAt` column in the database, but other fields still the same. Any idea?

**Update:** This happens when I run some of queries in other functions and pass t (transaction) to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this I think this will work here I am using `async await` not promise based method. Transaction I have used is [Managed transactions](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html#managed-transactions) Which is best to use if you want to use Transaction in your app

```js
updateUser: async (req, res) => {
    sequelize.sequelize.transaction(async (t1) => {

        let data = await User.findOne({
            where: {
                id: req.body.id
            }
        });
        if (data) {
            await User.update(req.body, { where: { id: req.body.id } });
            return res.status(200).send(error.OK);
        }
        else {
            return res.status(422).send(error.DATA_NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(500).send(error.SERVER_ERROR);
    });
}
```

Comment: You didn't pass the `transaction` to the queries. But let me check it.

Comment: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html

Comment: that's Unmanaged transactions you are using and you can see managed transactions below it which is best to use https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html#managed-transactions

Comment: Yes. with managed transactions it works fine. But, anyway, you see it passes the `t` even in managed transactions.

Comment: yes i have passed t1 because i have more transaction in other apis also like this https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html#concurrent-partial-transactions